# Newtx is blocking creation of a pdf

Tags: newtx

I have some problem with the newtx package.  The MiKTeX package manager says it is installed.  But when I try to run PDFLaTeX on this document no pdf is produced

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
p
\end{document}
```

The log file contains this error message:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file ntx-Regular-tlf-t1): Font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 
at 420 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I first had newtx installed automatically by WinEdt.  Then in case it would help I tried copying the newtx folder from another machine where it works fine (and ran Refresh FNDB).  That made no difference to the outcome or the error message.

Newtx is working fine for me on two other machines. They have font `ntx-Regular-tlf-t1` installed in the same place as the machine that produces the error.  That place is

```
MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/newtx
```

Copying that folder newtx from the machine where it does work to the machine where it does not made no difference.  I did run Refresh FNDB and Update Formats.  I get the exact same error message.

What can I do?

Comment: This means the databases of postscript fonts were not updated. Run from the command line, preferably as administrator  `updmap --verbose` (the switch is to see what happens).

Comment: @Bernard  Thanks, that worked.  Is there something I should do differently in MiKTeX updates to prevent this in the future?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It happens frequently with MiKTeX that `dvipd.map`, `pdftex.map` , &c.  are not updated to include the new `pfb`s, so it trie to make bitmap fonts. You just have to launch `updmap` if this ever happens again.